# Why can't find /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash

Tags: ros, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I  install ROS again.I have installed Ubutun 12.04 and I follow ROS fuerte installation instructions

I do the following:
1.add new source to the software sources - Go to Software Center -> Edit -> Software Sources.
2.Make sure all the first four checkboxes are checked: main, universe, restricted and multiverse.
3.Open Terminal, and execute the following command: sudo sh -c 'echo "deb ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
4.In terminal type: wget ???://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
5. sudo apt-get update .
6.Install ROS full version:sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full.

Notice：??? epual to http

Then there is something wrong as follow:
38 upgraded, 436 newly installed, 0 to remove and 245 not upgraded.
Need to get 402 MB/696 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,037 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe libsdl-image1.2 i386 1.2.10-3 [29.1 kB]
Get:2 ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-dynamic-reconfigure i386 1.4.2-s1367524085~precise [752 kB]
Get:3 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main g++-4.6 i386 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 [6,745 kB]
Get:4 ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-dynamic-reconfigure i386 1.4.2-s1367524085~precise [752 kB]
Get:5 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main g++-4.6 i386 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 [6,745 kB]
Get:6 ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-dynamic-reconfigure i386 1.4.2-s1367524085~precise [752 kB]
Get:7 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main g++-4.6 i386 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 [6,745 kB]
Get:8 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libasound2-dev i386 1.0.25-1ubuntu10.2 [70.2 kB]
Get:9 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libavahi-common-dev i386 0.6.30-5ubuntu2.1 [42.5 kB]
Get:10 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libdbus-1-dev i386 1.4.18-1ubuntu1.4 [212 kB]
Get:11 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libavahi-client-dev i386 0.6.30-5ubuntu2.1 [36.7 kB]
Get:12 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libtinfo-dev i386 5.9-4 [93.5 kB]
Get:13 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libncurses5-dev i386 5.9-4 [218 kB]
Get:14 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libslang2-dev i386 2.2.4-3ubuntu1 [526 kB]
Get:15 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libcaca-dev i386 0.99.beta17-2.1ubuntu2 [844 kB]
Get:16 ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-dynamic-reconfigure i386 1.4.2-s1367524085~precise [752 kB]
Get:17 ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-nodelet-core i386 1.6.5-s1367540629~precise [2,593 kB]
Get:18 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libfltk1.1-dev i386 1.1.10-10 [565 kB]
Get:19 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libnetpbm10 i386 2:10.0-15 [65.3 kB]
Get:20 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libnetpbm10-dev i386 2:10.0-15 [108 kB]
Get:21 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libogg-dev i386 1.2.2~dfsg-1ubuntu1 [63.3 kB]
Get:22 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libpulse-dev i386 1:1.1-0ubuntu15.4 [81.2 kB]
Get:23 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libsdl1.2-dev i386 1.2.14-6.4ubuntu3 [825 kB]
Get:24 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe libsdl-image1.2-dev i386 1.2.10-3 [32.7 kB]
Get:25 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libtheora-dev i386 1.1.1+dfsg.1-3ubuntu2 [393 kB]
Get:26 ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-ros-tutorials i386 0.2.20-0precise-20130502-1958-+0000 [480 kB]
Get:27 ???://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libyaml-dev i386 0.1.4-2ubuntu0.12.04.2 [66.5 kB]
Get:28 ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-common-tutorials i386 0.2.3-s1367618270~precise [4,510 kB]
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-common-tutorials i386 0.2.3-s1367618270~precise
Connection failed
Get:29 ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-geometry-tutorials i386 0.1.3-s1367618251~precise [527 kB]
Get:30 ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-flann i386 1.7.1-1precise-20130312-1306-+0000 [2,342 kB]
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-flann i386 1.7.1-1precise-20130312-1306-+0000
Connection failed
Get:31 ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-pcl i386 1.5.2-11precise-20130531-1434-+0000 [9,055 kB]
Get:32 ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-pcl i386 1.5.2-11precise-20130531-1434-+0000 [9,055 kB]
Get:33 ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-pcl i386 1.5.2-11precise-20130531-1434-+0000 [9,055 kB]
Get:34 ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-pcl i386 1.5.2-11precise-20130531-1434-+0000 [9,055 kB]
Get:35 ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-pcl i386 1.5.2-11precise-20130531-1434-+0000 [9,055 kB]
Get:36 ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-pcl i386 1.5.2-11precise-20130531-1434-+0000 [9,055 kB]
Get:37 ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-pcl i386 1.5.2-11precise-20130531-1434-+0000 [9,055 kB]
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-pcl i386 1.5.2-11precise-20130531-1434-+0000
Could not connect to packages.ros.org:80 (140.211.166.134). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-perception-pcl i386 1.2.5-s1371449992~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-laser-pipeline i386 1.4.5-s1371456634~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main yaml-cpp i386 0.2.7-5precise-20120502-0513-+0000
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-navigation i386 1.8.3-s1371470858~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-slam-gmapping i386 1.2.7-s1371489404~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-diagnostics i386 1.6.4-s1367540579~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-driver-common i386 1.4.0-s1367554820~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-image-common i386 1.8.0-s1367586547~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-robot-model i386 1.8.1-s1367616502~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-visualization-common i386 1.8.4-s1367586953~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-xacro i386 1.6.1-s1367525894~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-protobuf i386 0.1.0-s1367524828~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo i386 1.6.16-s1371456718~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-python-qt-binding i386 0.1.9-s1367564517~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-swig-wx i386 1.3.29-2precise-20130312-1308-+0000
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-rx i386 1.8.9-0precise-20130502-2002-+0000
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-visualization i386 1.8.17-s1371471259~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-opencv2 i386 2.4.2-1precise-20130312-1308-+0000
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-vision-opencv i386 1.8.8-s1367617226~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-geometry-experimental i386 0.2.3-s1367616748~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-robot-model-visualization i386 0.1.2-s1367564443~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-image-pipeline i386 1.8.5-s1371455677~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-diagnostics-monitors i386 1.4.3-s1367540724~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-geometry-visualization i386 0.1.1-s1367629388~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-physics-ode i386 1.8.0-s1367484976~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-executive-smach i386 1.2.1-s1367539865~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-stage i386 1.6.6-s1367616684~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-image-transport-plugins i386 1.8.6-s1367630328~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-visualization-tutorials i386 0.6.3-s1371490087~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-executive-smach-visualization i386 1.0.2-s1367554413~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-robot-model-tutorials i386 0.1.2-s1367485014~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Err ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-desktop-full i386 1.0.0-s1371562889~precise
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Fetched 7,263 kB in 1h 30min 27s (1,338 B/s)
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-common-tutorials/ros-fuerte-common-tutorials_0.2.3-s1367618270~precise_i386.deb  Connection failed
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-flann/ros-fuerte-flann_1.7.1-1precise-20130312-1306-+0000_i386.deb  Connection failed
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-pcl/ros-fuerte-pcl_1.5.2-11precise-20130531-1434-+0000_i386.deb  Could not connect to packages.ros.org:80 (140.211.166.134). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-perception-pcl/ros-fuerte-perception-pcl_1.2.5-s1371449992~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-laser-pipeline/ros-fuerte-laser-pipeline_1.4.5-s1371456634~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/y/yaml-cpp/yaml-cpp_0.2.7-5precise-20120502-0513-+0000_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-navigation/ros-fuerte-navigation_1.8.3-s1371470858~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-slam-gmapping/ros-fuerte-slam-gmapping_1.2.7-s1371489404~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-diagnostics/ros-fuerte-diagnostics_1.6.4-s1367540579~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-driver-common/ros-fuerte-driver-common_1.4.0-s1367554820~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-image-common/ros-fuerte-image-common_1.8.0-s1367586547~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-robot-model/ros-fuerte-robot-model_1.8.1-s1367616502~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-visualization-common/ros-fuerte-visualization-common_1.8.4-s1367586953~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-xacro/ros-fuerte-xacro_1.6.1-s1367525894~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-protobuf/ros-fuerte-protobuf_0.1.0-s1367524828~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo/ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo_1.6.16-s1371456718~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-python-qt-binding/ros-fuerte-python-qt-binding_0.1.9-s1367564517~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-swig-wx/ros-fuerte-swig-wx_1.3.29-2precise-20130312-1308-+0000_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-rx/ros-fuerte-rx_1.8.9-0precise-20130502-2002-+0000_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-visualization/ros-fuerte-visualization_1.8.17-s1371471259~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-opencv2/ros-fuerte-opencv2_2.4.2-1precise-20130312-1308-+0000_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-vision-opencv/ros-fuerte-vision-opencv_1.8.8-s1367617226~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-geometry-experimental/ros-fuerte-geometry-experimental_0.2.3-s1367616748~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-robot-model-visualization/ros-fuerte-robot-model-visualization_0.1.2-s1367564443~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-image-pipeline/ros-fuerte-image-pipeline_1.8.5-s1371455677~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-diagnostics-monitors/ros-fuerte-diagnostics-monitors_1.4.3-s1367540724~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-geometry-visualization/ros-fuerte-geometry-visualization_0.1.1-s1367629388~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-physics-ode/ros-fuerte-physics-ode_1.8.0-s1367484976~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-executive-smach/ros-fuerte-executive-smach_1.2.1-s1367539865~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-stage/ros-fuerte-stage_1.6.6-s1367616684~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-image-transport-plugins/ros-fuerte-image-transport-plugins_1.8.6-s1367630328~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-visualization-tutorials/ros-fuerte-visualization-tutorials_0.6.3-s1371490087~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-executive-smach-visualization/ros-fuerte-executive-smach-visualization_1.0.2-s1367554413~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-robot-model-tutorials/ros-fuerte-robot-model-tutorials_0.1.2-s1367485014~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
Failed to fetch ???://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-desktop-full/ros-fuerte-desktop-full_1.0.0-s1371562889~precise_i386.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:???:
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
zhi@ubuntu:~$

I can see that /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash doest exist /op/ is empty. And, I can not create a bash script for configuring your ROS workspace environment.

Any ideas? I have no clue, I will aprreciate any help.

Regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142636/why-can%27t-find-/opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash/) by [Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/13641/lee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-03-20**:
Are you sure you installed ROS fuerte and not another distribution like groovy or hydro? Check your folder in /opt/ros what is inside? If indeed there is a fuerte folder inside then probably something went wrong during the install process. Did you install ros with apt-get install?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-20**:
Did you check the file exists? What is the exact error message?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-21**:
Am I understanding you right that you installed ROS using apt-get and there is nothing under /opt?

**Comment by [Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/13641/lee/) on 2014-03-21**:
Hello,BennyRe. that's what i mean！is there someproblem?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-21**:
Yes this is definitely a problem. There should be your ROS installation. It seems like something went terribly wrong during installation. Try reinstalling ROS.

**Comment by [Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/13641/lee/) on 2014-03-21**:
So I must remove ROS, and reinstall ROS? when I use apt-get install ros,  I find  connection speed slow,is any effect to install ROS? Thank you,BennyRe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Slow connection speed is no problem as long as your connection is more or less stable.

Is seems like either your internet connection was down when you ran the above commands or packages.ros.org was down.

Please try the above commands again. Note that you only have to add the key once.

P.S. Please paste shell output in the code environment.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1